# Can't Modify Returned AJAX Variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I currently have the following JavaScript/jQuery script that gets an external html page using AJAX and runs a function on all it's text nodes.

```
$.get('webpage.html', function (html) {
    $(html).find('*').each(function () {
        $(this).contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType === 3 }).each(function () {
            this.nodeValue = foo(this.nodeValue);
            console.log(this.nodeValue);
        });
    console.log(html);                      
});
```

However although the logged new text node values have changed and are all correct, when I try to log the html at the end I just get what I started with, the original external webpage with none of the modifications in it.

What am I doing wrong?

DLiKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing `$(html)` and manipulating the results DOM tree cannot modify the original string.

Instead, you can write

```
var content = $('<div>' + html + '</div>');
//Modify content
html = content.html();
```

By wrapping the HTML in a `<div>`, I can easily retrieve the full source.

I wrote a [more detailed explanation](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/modifying-html-strings-using-jquery.html) on my blog.